# How to install WebPages v1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I have a web app that uses DLLs from this folder:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0`

Lately, my HD crashed and I had to reinstall everything, but I've installed the latest version of Visual Studio.

I have tried installing every MVC version that exists (I now have version 1 to 3 installed and MVC 4 runtime) and still I get no `v1.0` folder (only a `v2.0`).
My guess is that this came with an older version of Visual Studio or that MS has changed something on their MVC 1,2,3 installers and they don't include this package of DLLs.

**Does anyone know how can I install all the files that `v1.0` folder usually holds?**

I have tried installing separate DLLs from it using nuget, but things got worse with mixed DLL versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Here is what I have done:

- I first installed `AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateVS11Setup.exe` from here:
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491.
  This will add the `v1.0` folder. This seems to be an old version, but that's the best I could find...
- And then an installer called `AspNetMVC3.msi`, which I think came from here:
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44533

After that, it seemed working OK. :)